# Visualforce tab in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

I need place a visualforce page as tab in lightning experience. I created a visualforce tab and added it to salesforce1 navigation but it is not showing up.. I need to place a tab on the below place to open a VF page..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this feature will be coming out in Spring '16. Please see this link to Trailhead:

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_nav_setup

[image]